# Type traits for ConfigLoaders

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I recently added this ConfigLoader class to my project : it loads information (in this example for a window) from an XML config file, using boost. I would like to ask your advice if this is a good implementation of a ConfigLoader using type_traits, or if I could improve it; here is my code:

ConfigLoader.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <exception>
#include <type_traits>

namespace Spiky {
namespace Tags {

#define SPIKY_CONFIG_DEF_TYPES(ID, TYPE) \
struct TYPE : std::integral_constant<int, ID> { \
};

SPIKY_CONFIG_DEF_TYPES(1, DisplayConfig)
SPIKY_CONFIG_DEF_TYPES(2, GLSpecConfig)
#undef SPIKY_CONFIG_DEF_TYPES
} //namespace Tags

template <typename T>
class ConfigLoader {};
} //namespace Spiky
```

GraphicsDisplayConfig.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <exception>

#include "ConfigLoader.h"

namespace Spiky {

struct GraphicsDisplayConfig;
template<>
class ConfigLoader<Tags::DisplayConfig> {
public:
  static GraphicsDisplayConfig LoadConfig(const char* path) {
    GraphicsDisplayConfig config;
    try {
      boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
      boost::property_tree::read_xml(path, pt);

      title = pt.get<std::string>("display.title");
      config.x = pt.get<unsigned>("display.position.<xmlattr>.x");
      config.y = pt.get<unsigned>("display.position.<xmlattr>.y");
      config.w = pt.get<unsigned>("display.resolution.<xmlattr>.w");
      config.h = pt.get<unsigned>("display.resolution.<xmlattr>.h");
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
      BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << e.what();
    }
    return config;
  }
};

struct GraphicsDisplayConfig {
  unsigned x = 0;
  unsigned y = 0;
  unsigned w = 0;
  unsigned h = 0;
  std::string title = "";
  bool resizable = false;
  bool fullScreen = false;

  int LoadConfig(const char* path) {
    try {    
      boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
      boost::property_tree::read_xml(path, pt);

      title = pt.get<std::string>("display.title");
      x = pt.get<unsigned>("display.position.<xmlattr>.x");
      y = pt.get<unsigned>("display.position.<xmlattr>.y");
      w = pt.get<unsigned>("display.resolution.<xmlattr>.w");
      h = pt.get<unsigned>("display.resolution.<xmlattr>.h");
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
      BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << e.what();
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
};
}
```